# Create token secret for Third-party api in Kubernetes

Tags: rest, kubernetes, authorization, token

I started working in kubernetes and notice that there is one secret available in each namespace

```
# kubectl get secret
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-b2rzn   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      506d
```

this `default-token-XXXX` is token for service account with used by making kube-api call.

I have to do same type of thing, like we have some Third-party API. To access that API, we need token, and that token expire every 12 hours. I am thinking to create new secret as `ourapi-token-XXXX`, which will hold the token and there might be `CronJob` or `Daemon` in kubernetes which will check its expire time and update the value.

Lets take example of AWS or GCP API Token. This need to be renew automatically.

Goal is, when you try to access Third-party API, you don't need to generate token manually and get the valid token from kubernetes secrets.

Comment: I found this article online which describes [how to call the Kubernetes API from outside the cluster with Service Account JWT (JSON Web Token)](https://www.doit-intl.com/kubernetes-external-api-calls-the-right-way/) and it might be useful to help you with your issue.

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre thanks, but I am not looking to call kube-api to all from external. I want to create external api token in kubernetes. Like you have gcloud token or AWS token, those token I want to store in Kubernetes secrets.